# Regex With Conditional - Not Desired Output

Tags: regex

Was actually glossing over a question and found myself struggling to perform something really simple.
If a string contains `%` I want to use a particular regex, else I want to use a different one.

**I tried the following:** https://regex101.com/r/UvFZpo/1/

**Regex:** `(%)(?(1)[^$]+|[^%]+)`.

**Test string:** `abc%`

But I'm not getting the expected results.

I was expecting to see `abc%` matched as it contains `%`.
If the string was, `abc$`, I'd expect it to use the second expression.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Regex parses the string from left to right, position by position. Once it matches `&`, it is at the end of string, hence, it fails since there are no more chars to be matched by `[^$]+`. It is not quite clear though, what you need exactly in the end. Try `^(?:([^$]*%)|([^%]+))$` or simply `^(?:[^$]*%|[^%]+)$`.

Comment: Please post the sample input and your regex into this question. Apart from making the question complete per se, regex101 is blocked by my company's proxy, so I *can't* see it.

Comment: I'll check out what you provided soon @WiktorStribiżew. Also, edited per Bohemian's request.

Comment: I don't understand your regex - it requires the string to start with a % but your sample abc% doesn't so it will never match.

Comment: That works @WiktorStribiżew. My own einstellung getting in the way, I guess.

Comment: Done. Had forgot, meant to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex parses strings from left to right, position by position.

Once your pattern matches `&`, its index is at the end of string, hence, it fails since there are no more chars to be matched by the subsequent `[^$]+` pattern.

You can use a mere alternation here:

```
^(?:([^$]*%[^$]*)|([^%]+))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z7RKb9/2/)

If the string contains `%`, the Group 1 will be populated, else, Group 2 will.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:([^$]*%[^$]*)|([^%]+))` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `([^$]*%[^$]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `$`, as many as possible, `%` any 0+ chars other than `$`, as many as possible,
  - `|` - or
  - `([^%]+)` - any 1+ chars other than `%`, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.